# Kill dired buffers immediately in Emacs

Tags: emacs, dired

How can I achieve that when I search for a file with C-x d the buffer which showed me the possible completions will be killed automatically after opening the desired file?

Comment: The question is not too clear. What do you mean by "*the buffer which showed me the possible completions*"? Do you mean buffer `*Completions*`? If so, that buffer should be hidden as soon as you choose a candidate name (but it is not killed). I'm guessing that instead you mean the buffer that was current when you hit `C-x d`.  If so, please edit the question to make this clear.

Comment: To specify it a bit more precisely. If I press C-x d I can search for a file in the emacs command line. When I found it, I press 'Enter' and then a buffer with the name of the file opens and I have to press again the 'Enter' button to open the file. I know that if I press 'a' this buffer is gone, but I want to have the same behavior with the 'Enter' button.

Answer (score 5):

Simply use <kbd>a</kbd> in dired to open the file at point -- the dired buffer will be killed, and the chosen file visited in its place.

Answer (score 5):

In Emacs version>28 you can set new custom variable `dired-kill-when-opening-new-dired-buffer` to `t` to achieve this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following into your .emacs file:

```
(eval-after-load "dired"
  (lambda ()
    (put 'dired-find-alternate-file 'disabled nil)
    (define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "RET") #'dired-find-alternate-file)))
```

Then, when you visit the file in Dired using RET, you are calling
`dired-find-alternate-file`, so that the Dired buffer will be killed.